# How to speed up WholeStageCodegen in Spark SQL Query?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It's took about 2mins for one 248 MB file. 2 files ~ 5 mins
How can I tune or maximize the performance.

Initialize spark with below:

```
.setMaster(numCores)
.set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
.set("spark.executor.cores","2")
.set("spark.num.executors","2")
.set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors","2")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors","2")
.set("spark.ui.enabled","true")
.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",defaultPartitions)

joinedDf = upperCaseLeft.as("l")
          .join(upperCaseRight.as("r"), caseTransformedKeys, "full_outer")
          .select(compositeKeysCol ::: nonKeyCols.map(col => mapHelper(col,toleranceValue,caseSensitive)): _*)

data = joinedDf.take(1000)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeYww.png

Comment: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/why-code-generation-apache-spark-sql/read

Comment: So, what is the question actually?

Comment: Too long to get the explain? wholeStageCodeGen is optimizing of lazy eval code.